# DrawerLayout theme does not change from code

Tags: android

I want to make make it possible for users to change the theme of the app but drawer layout does not change theme. I don`t understand why.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Bobrarium"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

//...

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.Bobrarium" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>

    <style name="Theme.Bobrarium" parent="Base.Theme.Bobrarium" />
    <style name="dynamicTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.DynamicColors.DayNight"/>
</resources>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setTheme(R.style.dynamicTheme)

    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

navigation drawer now
[image]

navigation drawer if I set theme in xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    //...
    android:theme="@style/dynamicTheme">
    //...
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

maybe you need to set the theme for the drawerLayout separately?
I want the theme of the drawerLayout to change along with the whole theme
I don`t find questions with with a similar problem